# Error occurs when I compile AlamofireImage3.1

Tags: swift3, alamofire, xcode8, alamofireimage

When I compile AlamofireImage-3.1, following error occurs.
I also use Alamofire-4.0, but it seems to work well.

```
 @discardableResult
public func responseImage(
    _ imageScale: CGFloat = DataRequest.imageScale,
    inflateResponseImage: Bool = true,
    completionHandler: @escaping (DataResponse<Image>) -> Void)
    -> Self
{
    return response(
        responseSerializer: DataRequest.imageResponseSerializer(
            imageScale: imageScale,
            inflateResponseImage: inflateResponseImage
        ),
        completionHandler: completionHandler
    )
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Alamofire 3.x.x` supports `Swift2.2` & `Swift2.3` versions, while `Xcode8` uses the latest `Swift3` version.

So, `Alamofire 4.x.x` is compatible with `Xcode8` and that's reason it compiles without any error.

However, you can run `Swift2.2` or `Swift2.3` project or any framework without any error by following way:

1. Select Project or Pods Target
2. Go to `Build Settings`
3. Search for 'Swift Legacy Version`and make it`Yes`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
However, I now use Alamofire-4.0.